# Loading a lot of data onto Unity Editor before pushing Play button

Tags: unity-game-engine

As you know, Unity Editor owns graphic model and textures in its [Hierarchy](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Hierarchy.html).
This helps us develop games much faster: we push Play button, test code immediately, then push Stop, and modify code.

I have a big data to which to be loaded when the game starts. A lot of game information tables(not DB tables, but literally tables.) It takes a minute to load after I push Play button. If there is a way of loading the big tables before I push Play button, for example, Unity Editor loads it as it loads textures and models, I can save a lot of development time.

Is there a way of loading a big data other than models and textures onto Unity Editor, just like models and textures?

Answer (score 4):

Go to *Edit*--> *Preferences...* ---> *Cache Server* then enable Cache Server by changing it from *Disabled* to *Local* or *Remote* depending on where you want to save it.

If you choose *Remote* you have to download Cache Server from [here](https://unity3d.com/unity/team-license) then start it and plug the IP to the IP Address input filed in Unity.

[image]

This should help save loading time when you have large resources in your project.